# Javascript recursion for minesweeper

Tags: javascript, recursion, minesweeper

Update: I do not think this is duplicate, please see what it does now http://808md.net/miner/?n=12

I'm working on a minesweeper clone, a function checks if clicked cell is empty, and if so checks surrounding cells in recursive fashion, but I cannot make it work...

```
function checkCell (x,y) {
    if ($("[x='"+x+"'][y='"+y+"']").hasClass("cellOpen")) return;
    var c=-1; //exploded!
    if (_bombs[y][x]!="1") c=countAround (x,y);
    if (c>=0) {
    _field[y][x]=c;
    $("[x='"+x+"']    [y='"+y+"']").removeClass("cellClosed").addClass("cellOpen").css("color",_colors[c-1]);
    if (c>0) $("[x='"+x+"'][y='"+y+"']").html(c);
    }

   if (c==0) {
//if cell is empty, check surrounding 8 cells
      for (i=-1; i<=1; i++) {
    for (j=-1; j<=1; j++) {
        if (i!=0 || j!=0) {
        if ((x-0+j)>=0 && (y-0+i)>=0 && (x-0+j)<_x && (y-0+i)<_y) {
//This is supposed to be a recursion??
            checkCell (x-0+j,y-0+i);
        }
        }
    }
      }
    }
    return c;
}
```

I will add checks to ensure no infinite loops but for now it just goes diagonally top-left until meets a non-0 cell, instead of checking all surrounding ones.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recursive function to check 2d Array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686176/recursive-function-to-check-2d-array)

Comment: minesweeper can - must, in fact- be pre-computed, so that you have also at hand, for each each cell, the number of bombs around. Rewrite things this way and the end will be much easier.

Comment: That's what it does now...
http://808md.net/miner/?n=12